# Extra margin bottom[sample]?

Tags: html, css

I have this code : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/xJyS3/

There is a extra margin bellow the image in the frame, why? how do I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images are inline elements by default. Change them to block elements, and you are ready.

Inline images behave [image: A]s very big letters, as you can see, they want to stay on the same line as other letters, so you should modify this behavior by

- `vertical-align: top/bottom/negative length` http://jsfiddle.net/xJyS3/2/
- `float:left/right` on the image, `overflow:hidden` on its parent
  http://jsfiddle.net/xJyS3/3/
- `display: block` on the image: http://jsfiddle.net/xJyS3/1/
- and there are some other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because an image is inline by default, and so the extra margin is the difference between the anchor's baseline and bottom.  The solution is to make the image block level, so it fills the anchor properly.

```
a img {
    border: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
}
```